# Eigenvalues do not match between Eigen, Numpy, LAPACKE (Ubuntu), Intel MKL

Tags: numpy, lapack, eigen3, eigenvector

I have the following matrix **M** of doubles:

```
55.774375 61.0225 62.805625
-122.045 -125.61125 -122.045
62.805625 61.0225 55.774375
```

(the matrix is part of an algorithm to estimate the parameters of an ellipse from a 2D point cloud, see https://autotrace.sourceforge.net/WSCG98.pdf for reference).

And now comes the interesting part. Determining the eigenvalues and (right) eigenvectors of the matrix with different packages leads to different results for the (right) eigen**vectors**. Eigenvalues are for every package the same:

```
[-5.09420041e-13 -7.03125000e+00 -7.03125000e+00]
```

For numpy with python:

```python
M = np.array([[55.774375, 61.0225, 62.805625],
              [-122.045, -125.61125, -122.045, ],
              [62.805625, 61.0225, 55.774375]])

eval, evec = np.linalg.eig(M)
```

I get:

```
[[ 0.41608575  0.37443021 -0.80942954]
 [-0.80854518 -0.82367703  0.34119147]
 [ 0.41608575  0.42586167  0.47792489]]
```

With Eigen C++, the code looks as follows

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix3d M;
M << 55.774375, 61.0225, 62.805625,
     -122.045, -125.61125, -122.045,
      62.805625, 61.0225, 55.774375;
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> solver;
solver.compute(M);
```

I get for the eigenvectors

```
0.416086  0.376456 -0.462421
-0.808545 -0.823758  0.820878
0.416086  0.423914 -0.335151
```

With LAPACKE (apt install liblapack-dev lapacke lapacke-dev)

```cpp
double Marr[]{55.774375, 61.0225, 62.805625,
             -122.045, -125.61125, -122.045,
              62.805625, 61.0225, 55.774375};
char jobvl = 'N';
char jobvr = 'V';
int n=3;
int lda = n;
int ldvl = n;
int ldvr = n;
int lwork = -1;
int info;
double wr[n], wi[n], vl[ldvl*n], vr[ldvr*n];

LAPACKE_dgeev( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'V', n, Marr, lda, wr, wi,
              vl, ldvl, vr, ldvr );

if( info > 0 ) {
    printf( "The algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

I get for the eigenvectors

```
0.416086 0.376456 -0.788993
-0.808545 -0.823758 0.565975
0.416086 0.423914 0.239087
```

Similar are the results for Intel MKL.

I checked the determinant of M and it is close to zero (-4.0031989907207254e-05).

What I would like to understand is

1. Why do the eigenvectors for same eigenvalues differ so much between the libraries? Is this because of the different numerical methods used to approx them?
2. I understand that an Eigenvalue *d* has many associated eigenvectors, i.e. if *v* is the eigenvector for *d* than *q* * *v* (q being a scalar) is also an eigenvector of *d*. Since the second and the third eigenvalue are the same, I would assume that there is some scalar that transforms one into the other, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

My algorithm fails in C++ (in python it is working) due to the different eigenvectors. Is there a way out?

Comment: Your matrix appears to define a linear map that is planar as the determinant is zero (i.e. "no volume"). Hence only two of your eigenvectors are properly defined, which is why the packages differ in the third eigenvector (which has a zero eignevalue anyway).

Comment: If you have two identical eigenvalues `s_1 == s_2` with corresponding eigenvectors `v_1`, `v_2`, then every linear combination `a*v_1 + b*v_2` is also an eigenvector.